# creating na values in data frame for combinations

Tags: r

my data frame looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame (IDs  = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID1", "ID2", "ID3"),
                  dates = c("2021-03-07", "2021-03-07", "2021-03-08", "2021-03-08", "2021-03-07"),
                  measure1 = c(3, 2, 4, 5, 4),
                  measure2 = c(1, 7, 8, 3, 2))
```

Please note that there is no line for ID3 and the date of 2021-03-08.

Question: How can I generate the "missing line" with NA values? I have played with gather/spread but I can't find a way to get back clean column names just like they were before (due to the multiple measure columns).

My data set has five metrics, not two. Thank you very much for your help, it's greatly appreciated.

EDIT: expanded df:

```
df <- data.frame (IDs  = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID1", "ID2", "ID3"),
att  = c("cmp", "cmp", "adr", "adr", "adr"),
dates = c("2021-03-07", "2021-03-07", "2021-03-08", "2021-03-08", "2021-03-07"), measure1 = c(3, 2, 4, 5, 4), measure2 = c(1, 7, 8, 3, 2))
```

The proposed solution

```
df %>%
  complete(IDs, nesting(dates))
```

gives me an NA in "att" in the new line that has been added for ID3. However, I would like to keep the value "adr" in this cell. It is always the same for all ID3 records. This is all very new to me, so thank you for your patience.

Comment: Use `tidyr::complete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  complete(IDs, nesting(dates))

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  IDs   dates      measure1 measure2
  <chr> <chr>         <dbl>    <dbl>
1 ID1   2021-03-07        3        1
2 ID1   2021-03-08        4        8
3 ID2   2021-03-07        2        7
4 ID2   2021-03-08        5        3
5 ID3   2021-03-07        4        2
6 ID3   2021-03-08       NA       NA
```

In case you choose not use `tidyr::complete`, you can make use of `tidyr::pivot_wider` and `tidyr::pivot_longer` to make implicit `NA` values into explicit:

```
df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "dates", values_from = c("measure1", "measure2")) %>%
  pivot_longer(!IDs, names_to = c(".value", "dates"), 
               names_pattern = "(measure\\d)_(.*)")

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  IDs   dates      measure1 measure2
  <chr> <chr>         <dbl>    <dbl>
1 ID1   2021-03-07        3        1
2 ID1   2021-03-08        4        8
3 ID2   2021-03-07        2        7
4 ID2   2021-03-08        5        3
5 ID3   2021-03-07        4        2
6 ID3   2021-03-08       NA       NA
```

Comment: Super many thanks for sharing your answer. With the first solution (which looks very clean and readable) I generate some "NA" values that I don't need, because my data has some more attributes (which are tied to "ID").  Is there a way to generate all possible "dates" and "ID" combinations, while leaving additional attributes alone? So let's assume I have an additonal column att  = c("cmp", "cmp", "adr", "adr", "adr") which is always the same for each ID.

Comment: Is `week` another variable in your data set? Could you share its value so that I can add it here and test.

Comment: sorry I meant "dates" - I edited the comment.

Comment: In `att` are values in correct order for your data sample? and Apart from `dates` and `IDs` that would would like all possible combinations for, would you like to your additional variables to be there or just omitted?

Comment: Hello Anoushiravan - thank you for your help with this. I should probably add to the question. Yes, att is another column in the correct order. I need all "implicit missing lines" for the combination ID and date. The additional values should be there - they are the same for every line with the same ID and date combination.

Comment: Check this please: `df %>%
  complete(nesting(IDs, dates, att))` If that's not what you are looking for please edit your data sample and expected output again so they correspond in variables and dimension.

Comment: Thank you, my solution to achieve was to separate "att" and other dimensions in my data from the relevant ones and then rejoin them. This was great help. I don't have enough rep on here so I can't upvote.

Comment: It's ok upvote doesn't matter for me. But if you need to get help here it's essential to share a clear expected output and also a sample data that best represents your original one so you have better chances of getting relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

In base R you may use `expand.grid` on `IDs` and `dates`, and make them `unique`. Then just `merge` with your data frame.

```
merge(df, unique(expand.grid(df$IDs, df$dates)), 
      by.x=c('IDs', 'dates'), by.y=c('Var1', 'Var2'), all=TRUE)
#   IDs      dates measure1 measure2
# 1 ID1 2021-03-07        3        1
# 2 ID1 2021-03-08        4        8
# 3 ID2 2021-03-07        2        7
# 4 ID2 2021-03-08        5        3
# 5 ID3 2021-03-07        4        2
# 6 ID3 2021-03-08       NA       NA
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I can't upvote - not enough rep...

Comment: @jazzyjay You can [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) though and earn +2 rep with it ;)